# What should I use for continuous integration given my circumstances?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration

I'm developing a project in C# using VS2010. I'm using svn 1.7 for my version control. What I want is a (FREE) tool that runs on the build server and checks for fresh commits. If the commit breaks the trunk then I want email notifications sent (I have a sendmail openbsd server on the network I can use). I also want this tool (or another tool) to run all my MSTest tests periodically and send emails if there is a failed test.

Any suggestions? I already built my own crude windows service to check for failed builds. But this was before I heard that tools for this sort of thing already exist. I could easily have this thing run all my tests with mstest.exe and then parse the xml results files, but I'm wondering if my time would be better spent just installing and configuring a proper tool for all of this.

There will be at most 4 developers.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some experience with TeamCity and Hudson/Jenkins. 
I found TeamCity fairly easy to setup and it seems to meet your needs of:

- MSTest integration out of the box
- Email notifications

TeamCity is free for up to 20 build configurations and has an easy to use Web/GUI interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these things

Comment: teamcity was a breeze to set up.

Comment: TeamCity is rock solid. It's a great product.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CruiseControl.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/)

- built in support for Subversion
- no limits on number of build configurations
- email notifications using the 'Email Publisher'
- web interface and desktop build notifications via [CCTray](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCTray)